# How do I prevent programs from giving a folder a name?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

In my particular case, I have Yandex.Disk installed and the folder it syncs is given the name Yandex.Disk but the actual folder name is something else. In the example below, the actual folder name is YandexDisk but the program gave it the name Yandex.Disk.

[image: Given name]

[image: Actual name]

Comment: So you're complaining that the display name is different than actual name on disk?

Comment: Yes. It's confusing.

Comment: You should ask the software manufacturer to fix this. My apps use the folder names I provide.

Comment: @John They won't "fix this" because they consider it a feature. Windows does this for folder name translation since Vista, by the way.

Comment: It is a software vendor issue, not a Windows issue so you will have to live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hidden file called `desktop.ini` inside that folder. It gives it the icon and alternative name.

Click the address bar like you did in the 2nd screenshot and instead of path type `cmd`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open command line. Then use this command to unhide the file:

```
attrib -s -h desktop.ini
```

Delete the file or edit it with Notepad to remove the alternative name. Then hide it again:

```
attrib +s +h desktop.ini
```

The program may however decide to restore this file to its original content. There's unfortunately nothing you can do about this.